What is RDP Event ID 142 and 143?
My servers, as one can imagine, are constantly under attack.  I manage them using RDP and I block RDP connections by only allowing my static IP address to access RDP.  I recently moved from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2022 and of course I blocked all IP address other than mine to RDP.  I'm getting a bunch of of Event ID 142 and 143 entries that are "TCP socket READ operation failed" and "TCP socket WRITE operation failed" events in the log.  I don't know what's going on and I'm concerned that this is another form of attack on RDP.  Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Apparently no one knows.
